# Any way to ignore Caliburn Messages at design-time

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

We use Caliburn Micro on a project that has a number of fairly complex (lots of UI components) WPF windows.

An example of our problem is for the ListBoxes on these windows we only have the ItemSource pointing to collections in the ViewModel which happily returns our data and we have no further requirement for any other binding.

The main problem comes when we run the project within Visual Studio (10) and open these windows, Caliburn spends tens of seconds reporting messages such as :-

```
2014-02-01 05:42:33.6103|INFO|Caliburn.Micro.ViewModelBinder|Binding Convention Not Applied: 
Element listBoxAccount did not match a property.

2014-02-01 05:42:37.7968|INFO|Caliburn.Micro.ViewModelBinder|Binding Convention Not Applied: 
Element InnerBorder_Chcked did not match a property.
2014-02-01 05:42:37.7968|INFO|Caliburn.Micro.ViewModelBinder|Binding Convention Not Applied: 
Element OuterBorder_Center did not match a property.2014-02-01 
05:42:43.1767|INFO|Caliburn.Micro.ViewModelBinder|Binding Convention Not Applied: Element 
SelectionRect did not match a property.
```

It runs through hundreds of these messages.

Whilst we understand (I think) that is just CM iterating the components trying to bind everything it is very frustrating waiting for a window to open, especially as we don't care that these issues exist and have no requirement for the binding issues CM is alerting us to.

The time delay doesn't seem to exist when not running the application within Visual Studio (even just the debug version) so I hope this is not having any impact on release.

My question, therefore, is; is there any way we can disable or supress these errors (or perhaps flag these properties as not for binding) to make debugging much quicker?

Many thanks.

James.

Answer (score 0):

Slighty too big for a comment, although I'm not sure this will solve your problem:

Have you specifically set up Design-Time support? I didn't think it was something `Caliburn.Micro' attempted to do by default.

This might help you out on the offending `Windows`:

```
<Window 
   ... Other code ...
cal:Bind.AtDesignTime="True">
```

Source: [Design-Time Support](https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Design-Time%20Support).

Comment: Hi - sorry for delay. I don't think this will help as it's actually during compilation and startup the problem occurs and not during the actual designing of the windows.

Comment: Ah, the title was slightly misleading. I'll have another crack and replicating the problem.

Comment: Sorry Chris perhaps it was.  It should have said at compile time.

Comment: No worries - Haven't got round to having a second look yet =D